# How to get raw html from a $refs?

Tags: vue.js

I need to retrieve raw HTML from a component and then insert it into a textarea.

For that I wrapped my component in a DIV:

```
<div id="content" ref="content">
  <Nl v-bind:json="json" />
</div>
```

When my json change I would like to get a raw html of the generated text based on my json:

```
watch: {
    json: function (val) {
        console.log(this.$refs.content);
        console.log(this.$refs.content.innerHTML);
        this.rawHtml = ???;
    }
},
```

Here's what I get with my two console.log():

[image: Console log results]

The innerHtml give me a html comment?! **How can I get a raw html of `this.$refs.content` ?**

Comment: try this : this.$refs.content.$el.innerHTML

Comment: Adding onto @harshitpandey, next time use console.dir(this.$refs.content) and you'll be able to see the entire object.

Comment: @harshitpandey `this.$refs.content` is not a custom element so it wont have $el property.

Comment: @NafeesAnwar You're right `this.$refs.content.$el` is undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have to wait the DOM being updated before reading it. You can use **$nextTick**.

```
watch: {
    json(val) {
        this.$nextTick().then(() => {
            console.log(this.$refs.content);
            console.log(this.$refs.content.innerHTML);
            this.rawHtml = this.$refs.content.innerHTML;
        });
    }
},
```

Works fine for me.